# Combining multiple columns into single range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with several lists of names like such:

```
A     | B     | C
Joe   | Steve | Mike
Steve | Dave  | Alex
Sarah | Mike  | Joe
Beth  | Jane  | Steve
```

I'm trying to consolidate all the names in those columns down to a single range (such as can be used by `unique()`) so that users can be selected from a dropdown.
Adding a multi-column range to `unique()` returns a multi-column result based on the uniqueness of each multi-column row (i.e. if 'Sarah, Mike, Joe' above were repeated, that would filter down to a single entry in the results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER({A1:A;B1:B;C1:C},{A1:A;B1:B;C1:C}<>""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks @player0.  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I was using the {;;} grouping incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ",1,TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:C),,50000))), " ")))
```

[image: 0]